# Is Async useful for DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

For example, if I have window scroll and mouse move listeners on the browser, which manipulates multiple elements each (calling multiple functions), would it be beneficial to call the functions asynchronously?

```
async function hello(){
  try{
    method1(); // a bunch of DOM manipulation
    method2(); // a bunch of other unrelated DOM manipulation
  }
  catch(err){}
}
```

vs

```
function hello(){
  method1();
  method2();
}
```

Would the 1st one be faster? Also do the async methods run in parallel by default if I don't use 'await' for my methods?

Comment: if the methods are sync, there's no point.

Comment: An `async` function without `await` only differs from a standard function in what it returns, not in its synchronous aspects.

Comment: Nothing in javascript "runs in parallel", it is single threaded.

Comment: it's sometimes useful to let the ui render before performing the next action (I use a 0ms timeout usually) It won't actually make things faster but it seems faster sometimes if you can render UI stuff before doing expensive calculations

Comment: @IrkenInvader The above `async function` won't help with that though

Comment: Why does your first code snippet catch exceptions but your second doesn't?